# Filter by multiple classes then arrange list from most relevant?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using jquery/javascript to filter a list by multiple classes after selecting 3 features from select boxes. Right now, it is showing whatever has all three criteria and then putting the rest in another div on the page.

I'm wondering if there's a way to not just show the items that match all three criteria but two or one criteria also - and then if it meets no criteria be at the bottom of the list or something like that.

I'm just messing around so completely open to any suggestions on a way to do something like this using jquery/javascript.

```
<form id="keys" action="results.html">
<select id="key1">
<option id="Android">Android</option>
<option id="Bluetooth">Bluetooth</option>
<option id="Camera">Camera</option>
<option id="Smartactions">Smartactions</option>
<option id="Video">Video</option>
<option id="Cat">Meow</option>
</select>

<select id="key2">
<option id="Android">Android</option>
<option id="Bluetooth">Bluetooth</option>
<option id="Camera">Camera</option>
<option id="Smartactions">Smartactions</option>
<option id="Video">Video</option>
</select>

<select id="key3">
<option id="Android">Android</option>
<option id="Bluetooth">Bluetooth</option>
<option id="Camera">Camera</option>
<option id="Smartactions">Smartactions</option>
<option id="Video">Video</option>
</select>
</form>
<button id="submit" onclick="showList()">Submit</button>

<div id="results">
<ul>
<li class="Bluetooth Camera" style="display:none">DEFY PRO</li>
<li class="Bluetooth Camera Smartactions" style="display:none">Motorola RAZR V</li>
<li class="Bluetooth Camera Smartactions" style="display:none">ATRIX HD LTE</li>
<li class="Android Bluetooth Camera Smartactions Video" style="display:none">Motorola RAZR</li>
<li class="Bluetooth Camera Video" style="display:none">MOTO LUXE</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="rest_results">

</div>
```

And my script

```
function showList() {

    var key1 = keys.key1.value;
    var key2 = keys.key2.value;
    var key3 = keys.key3.value;

    var filter = $("." + key1 + "." + key2 + "." + key3 + "");
    filter.show();

    if (filter.length == 0) {
        alert("There is nothing that matches your criteria");   
    }

    var rest = $('li').not(filter);
    rest.show().appendTo("#rest_results");
}
```

and a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bZkp3/)

Answer (score 0):

ID of elements must be **unique**.

You can use `data-*` attribute instead of that.

I don't know weather or not I understand, but here is the updated code. You can select only one, two or three criteria,

## HTML

```
<form id="keys" action="results.html">
  <select id="key1">
      <option></option>
      <option data-filter="Android">Android</option>
      <option data-filter="Bluetooth">Bluetooth</option>
      <option data-filter="Camera">Camera</option>
      <option data-filter="Smartactions">Smartactions</option>
      <option data-filter="Video">Video</option>
      <option data-filter="Cat">Meow</option>
  </select>

  <select id="key2">
      <option></option>
      <option data-filter="Android">Android</option>
      <option data-filter="Bluetooth">Bluetooth</option>
      <option data-filter="Camera">Camera</option>
      <option data-filter="Smartactions">Smartactions</option>
      <option data-filter="Video">Video</option>
  </select>

  <select id="key3">
      <option></option>
      <option data-filter="Android">Android</option>
      <option data-filter="Bluetooth">Bluetooth</option>
      <option data-filter="Camera">Camera</option>
      <option data-filter="Smartactions">Smartactions</option>
      <option data-filter="Video">Video</option>
  </select>
</form>
<button id="submit" onclick="showList()">Submit</button>

<br>
<div id="results">
<ul>
    <li class="Bluetooth Camera" style="display:none">DEFY PRO</li>
    <li class="Bluetooth Camera Smartactions" style="display:none">Motorola RAZR V</li>
    <li class="Bluetooth Camera Smartactions" style="display:none">ATRIX HD LTE</li>
    <li class="Android Bluetooth Camera Smartactions Video" style="display:none">Motorola RAZR</li>
    <li class="Bluetooth Camera Video" style="display:none">MOTO LUXE</li>
</ul>
</div>

<br>
<div id="rest_results">


</div>
```

## JAVASCRİPT

```
function showList() {

    var key1 = $("#key1").find(":selected").data("filter");
    var key2 = $("#key2").find(":selected").data("filter");
    var key3 = $("#key3").find(":selected").data("filter");
    var selectorArr = [];
    var selector;

    if (typeof key1 !== "undefined")
        selectorArr.push("."+key1);
    if (typeof key2 !== "undefined")
        selectorArr.push("."+key2);
    if (typeof key3 !== "undefined")
        selectorArr.push("."+key3);
    selector = selectorArr.join(", ");

    if (selector != "") {
       var filter = $(selector);
       if (filter.length == 0)
           alert("There is no match with your criteria!");
       filter.show();
       var rest = $('li').not(selector);
       $("#rest_results").html("<b>Rest of the results</b>");
       rest.clone().show().appendTo("#rest_results");
    }
    else {
       alert("You must select at least one criteria!");  
    }

}
```

[here is the updated jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bZkp3/3/).